# Remove Cancel button of New Item form from SP Modal Dialog

Tags: sharepoint-server, splistitem, modal-dialog, jsom

Using below code I am loading share point new list item form  in the SP Modal Dialog. Now I want to hide Cancel button of that form.

How can I do that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var context;
var web;
var user;
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl ;
//var loginName = _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;
//alert(loginName)
var currentLoggedinUser = _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName;
var userTitle;
var flag=true;
var options = { title: "Announcements - New Item",url:"http://sp-qc-01:2525/Lists/testSurvey/NewForm.aspx"};
function init() {
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = context.get_web();
getCurrentUser();

}

function getCurrentUser() {
user = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(user);

context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSucces, onGetUserNameFail);
}
function onGetUserNameSucces() {
// TODO: implement your own succes handler

retrieveListItems();
}
function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
// TODO: implement your own fail handler and do some logging
}


function retrieveListItems() {
      var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('testSurvey');
     var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Author\' /><Value Type=\'User\'>'+ user.get_title()+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
     this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery); 
    context.load(collListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {       

    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();


   //alert(collListItem.get_count());
   if(collListItem.get_count()==0)
   {
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
   }
    //alert(listItemInfo.toString());

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below Script to hide the Cancel button.

```
$("input[value$='Save']").hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the settings you can pass to `SP.UI.ModalDialog` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx)

Unfortunately, you can't open the dialog without "cancel" button in it.

What you can do is to edit `NewForm.aspx` page.

1. Go to your list/library
2. Click "new", this will redirect you to `NewForm.aspx`
3. Edit Page
4. Add Content Editor Web Part somewhere above your form
5. Add the following css to your CEWP:

   `input.ms-ButtonHeightWidth[value="Cancel"] { display: none; }`
6. Save the page